# Mysql LIKE %...% together with table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with phone numbers.
In Table A I have to delete all phone numbers thats not in Table B.

In Table B the phonenumbers are with conterycode, but in Table A they are without conterycode.

I therefor try to use a command similar to LIKE %Phonenumber%

I have tried this code, but that is giving me a syntax error

```
DELETE FROM temp_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE WorkTelephoneNumber LIKE temp_table.%PhoneNumber%
);

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%PhoneNumber%
)' at line 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
DELETE FROM temp_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE WorkTelephoneNumber LIKE concat('%',temp_table.PhoneNumber,'%')
);
```

Comment: Country code is at the beginning, i think '%PhoneNumber' is enough, so : WHERE WorkTelephoneNumber LIKE concat('%',temp_table.PhoneNumber)

Answer (score 1):

A subquery will be very slow. you can use join instead

```
Delete t1 from temp_table t1 
join TableB on tableB.WorkTelephoneNumber like concat('%',t1.PhoneNumber,'%')
```